# The Friedman's test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, normality-assumption

I have conducted research on the impact of toys on reading comprehension among primary school children. I have tested the strategy with three types of English language learners; good, intermediate and weak. There were five different sessions in each of the group. However, the scores were not normally distributed. Thus, I have conducted the Mann-Whitney test in order to identify any significant differences between the toys and rereading groups. Meantime, I have also conducted the Kruskal-Wallis test to identify any significant differences among the three different types of learners in each of the group. Another point is I have to identify the means differences within the sessions in the toys group. Can I conduct the Friedman's Test in order to determine the significant changes within each of the sessions in a group? Can I use the ANOVA and ANCOVA repeated measures by assuming they are robust to violations of normality?